# asp.net textbox with TextMode="MultiLine" default height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a textbox with TextMode="SingleLine" working great on a asp.net web page.
Now I need to set TextMode="MultiLine" so that the textbox can expand when needed.
The problem is that when TextMode="SingleLine" the default height is 22px but when I change it to TextMode="MultiLine" the default height is now 37px.
The height is 37px even if there is only one line of text.

Is there some way to make the "multiline" textbox have the same height of the "singleline" textbox when there is only one line of text?

Maybe there is some CSS, JavaScript, or JQuery magic???

Comment: CSS. Just give it a height via Style

Comment: Just modify your `Site.css` :)

Comment: Added style="height:22px;" directly to the textbox and it still starts at 37px.

Comment: You were both correct. It seems that there is some "higher" style that is altering the height. Thanks for the help.